# Configuração do Debug do Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classes, debug

Boa tarde.

Estou com um problema para debuggar meu projeto no Eclipse. Classes nativas de java estão aparecendo no processo de depuração quando as únicas classes que me são interessantes são as que fazem parte de meu projeto. Como opto por não visualizar classes nativas do Java?

Grato!

Comment: Isso acontece quando o fluxo chega no breakpoint? vc manda ele entrar no código?

Comment: Se eu fosse você não faria isso. Pode se confundir quando algum método lançar exceção.

Answer (score 1):

Acione ou/e configure o Debug Step Filtering:

`Window - Preferenes - Java - Debug - Step Filtering`

A opção `Use Step Filter` deve estar acionada e as classes/pacotes que não quer depurar marcados (no mínimo `java.*` e `javax.*`).

Veja abaixo um exemplo:

[image: Screenshot Preferences]

se estiver faltando o pacote/classe em questão - `java.*` e `javax.*` - é só usar o respectivo botão da esquerda: `Add Packages...` ou `Add Class...` para selecionar pacotes ou classes; ou `Add Filter...` para entrar em forma de texto.

**Obs:** tambem existe um botão na tela (Perspective) do debugger para acionar/desligar o uso do Step Filter diretamente (Shift+F5).

Comment: No Use Step Filter havia apenas a opção java.Lang.ClassLoader, retirei ela no entanto, as classes como String.class ou Pattern.class ainda estão sendo mostradas no debug.